# Getting the date of the first day of the week

Tags: python, datetime

I have records in a table which have a date field.

I would like to query the table so that the records returned are only the Sunday's date of a given week.

How could I use python's `datetime` library to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: This question has a vote to close as "unclear".  It's not my vote, but I agree with it: I think the reason is that the question you asked in the body does not match the title.   Your body tells us that you already have (in a record) the date of the Sunday of the week, and asks "how can I use `datetime` to query the table to get records from the same week?".   But your title asks (and your own answer answers) "how can I get the date of the sunday of the week".     You need to clean this up: what really are you asking?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To get the beginning date of the week from Sunday:

```
datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=datetime.today().isoweekday() % 7)
```

Comment: isoweekday can't be greater than 7 so why the % 7?

Comment: @Aerodyno it can be equal to 7 (Sunday) and 7 % 7 = 0

Answer (score 30):

Thanks @PavSidhu and editors of that answer. Building further on that answer:

**If your start of week is Sunday**

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=datetime.datetime.today().isoweekday() % 7)
```

**If your start of week is Monday**

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.today()  - datetime.timedelta(days=datetime.datetime.today().weekday() % 7)
```

**If you want to calculate start of week for a future date**

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

# 5 days ahead of today
future_date = datetime.datetime.today() + relativedelta(days=5)

# If Start of Week is Monday
print(future_date - datetime.timedelta(days=future_date.weekday() % 7))

# If start of week is Sunday
print(future_date - datetime.timedelta(days=future_date.isoweekday() % 7))
```

Diff: When start of week is Monday, we are using [`weekday()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday) instead of [`isoweekday()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoweekday)

- `isoweekday()` - Monday is 1 and Sunday is 7
- `weekday()` - Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6

Comment: Very specific answer, Made my day THanks