# How can I get all the dates of current week?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a use case where I need to count the server failures for current week. I am counting by reading a file where all the dates and failures are given. But I need to Calculate weekly failures, So I thought of to get all the dates in current week and compare that with dates in file and hence count the failures. So the question is how can I get all the dates of current week ? Also, how can i check if any date comes in that week?
Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the date of the first day of the week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39441639/getting-the-date-of-the-first-day-of-the-week)

Comment: And to advance a day, [please consult these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3240458/1270789).

Comment: No, it doesn't actually. I have already done whats there in please consult these answers. I am looking for something better. I need dates of all the days in current week so far.

Comment: Ahh, ok! you are saying to use both the above links. Calculate first day of the week and then get the dates for rest of the days. Let me try that.

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas:

```
df.loc[df["dates"].dt.week == week_number]
```

This simply gets all the rows where week is equal to the specified week (you can find out that week by trying a dummy value and using `.dt.week`).

Answer (score 0):

```
print(date.today())
for x in range(7):
    print(date.today() + timedelta(days=x))
```